Issues with elogind auto-lock and auto sleep
I have a laptop. I use openrc init system and hence use a elogind service to manage my X session instead of systemd.
I want to achieve the following when the user is inactivity for total time of 7 mins,(also the laptop is not connected t)

Trigger screensaver(blank screen == dpms off) after 180 secs (3 mins mark)
Trigger slock locker utility after the next 120 secs and not wake the screen again (5 mins mark)
Get the laptop to sleep after the next 120 secs (7 mins mark)

Here is what I have tried,
# Set screensaver after 3 mins of inactivity, Lock screen on elogind events, Lock screen after 5 mins of inactivity.
xset s on &
xset s 180 120 &
xss-lock slock &
xautolock -locker slock -detectsleep -corners +-00 &

The above code snippet is taken from this arch wiki. As expected the screen locks after 5 mins. But there is no blank screen or my laptop screen does not turn off after 3 mins.
What I understand from this and some other random experiments is that as soon as the screensaver is triggered, the locker utility is triggered.
Also tried this solution suggested in reddit,
xset s on &
xss-lock slock &
xautolock -time 5 -locker "xset s activate; xset dpms force off " -detectsleep -corners +-00 &

But this does not satisfy my requirement, but this is something that I am using currently as it working as expected.
Can anyone suggest what is wrong with the commands I have used?
Furthermore, I would like to know how to achieve the 3rd requirement.
